# Is not a function error when calling async method?

Tags: nuxt.js

Where am I going wrong with this page file? I just want to call the test method on mounted.

```
<template>
    <div class="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    async test() {
        let result = await axios.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two');
        console.log(result);
    },
    mounted() {
        this.test();
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to execute the `asyncData`, you don't need to use the mounted object method, and you don't even need to use a name function like `test`

for more information please visit [nuxtjs async-data documetion](https://fr.nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/)

```
<template>
    <div class="container"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  async asyncData({ params }) {
        let result = await 
           axios.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two');
        console.log(result);
    },

};
</script>
```

Comment: This is nuxt, every example ive seen is outside of methods

Comment: what you are looking for is asyncData function and it will be executed in the server-side, and you can't call it within the mounted method as it is executed before even the component is mounted, check my update

Comment: Thanks Thamer - so how would you call it?

Comment: It will be executed automatically on the server side before the page show up in your browser (nuxtjs has it's own default implementation ), and you should return the data if you want to show it within the page,